# django form + weird behavior with arrays

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a `clean` function for my form, and in it I have the below:

```
tags = cleaned_data.get("tags")
logger.info('got to clean function ' + str(tags))
```

When I output the `tags` value, I see: `[ '1', '2', '3' ]`. In my template, when I want to recreate the html for it, I have a template_tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def generate_tags(tags):
    print str(tags)
    # Code to produce the html
```

and I'm calling it via: `{% generate_tags form.tags %}`.

However, when I finish the `print` command in the template function im getting:

```
<input type="hidden" name="event_tags" value="3" id="id_event_tags_0" />
```

Why isn't it giving me the array as I was seeing in the clean function?? Is there a way for me to get the array before the `clean` function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly this is not documented anywhere. For anybody else stuck on the same problem, if you have a `form` object, you can do:

```
form['field_name'].value()
```

This gives the value *before* it is cleaned or validated.